# The package plymouth needs to be reinstalled ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, plymouth

Does anybody know how I can reinstall plymouth in Ubuntu 16.04?

For several days the system has reported errors from package manager. It's telling me that package is broken with this message:

> The package plymouth needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt update` and try to search again?

Comment: You can reinstall any package using `sudo apt install --reinstall <package>`